# Having trouble getting values using quick.db in discord.js (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, discord.js, quick.db

I am writing a discord bot in typescript and can't seem to retrieve data. I can see the user ids in the JSON.sqlite file but I can't figure out why it returns `null` when I retrieve data. If you want to see my code I have it on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/UDUK4rmm) with a couple of comments.

Comment: Linking to other sites makes the question of limited use to future visitors if the link ever breaks. Please reduce your code to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add it to the question body.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
console.log(economy.get(`${msg.author.id}.money`))
```

is wrong. You probably want

```
console.log(economy.get(msg.author.id).money)
```

**Reason:**
`${}` is making a template string, which indeed puts the variable into a string, however, you don't need to do this as passing in the value in the first place will do it anyways. However, you are trying to access the `money` property from `msg.author_id`, which doesn't exist. Therefore, it returns null and SQLite can't find a `null` entry.

Comment: I tried this and I understand why yours is right but it still returns null and I don't understand why

Comment: Can you tell me what `console.log(msg.author.id)` outputs?

Comment: ```null``` I don't understand why it won't work because what I can see is the id then the object that contains the money in json.sqlite

Comment: If `msg.author.id` is null then it won't be able to lookup the ID

Comment: I am dumb! I thought you said ```console.log(db.get(msg.author.id)`` but what you said returns my id

Comment: Hmm interesting, what does `console.log(economy.get(msg.author.id))` output? (without .money)

Comment: It is null from earlier (sorry for the slow responses

Answer (score 0):

quick.db needs async/await because it uses promise-mysql and returns a promise.

Comment: Note that the question's OP was using quick.db v7 or below, meaning its methods were not async.

Comment: I don't see that stated anywhere, but if that is the case then sure i guess.